# Lost my java packages and project from eclipse package explorer

Tags: eclipse, package-explorer

I have been recently working on android app development on eclipse and suddenly I find that my package explorer has got blank, I am not able to locate my previous packages and project from eclipse package explorer but I can still locate it on my work-space folder. Please, help me to restore my projects and packages.

Comment: Do you have any working sets?

Comment: no, my all projects are deleted from explorer and it is prompting to create new projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have deleted the project (by default it leaves the source files on your workspace).

Try right-clicking, import Java project, locate your project in your workspace. That should solve the issue.

Comment: I have to create new blank projects(folder) for this and then import my previous project to that folder. Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: No, you misunderstand me. Just right click on the project explorer in Eclipse. Select import, then Java project. Browse your workspace, and there you can select *all* the projects you closed.